# Why do I see duplicate warnings in Eclipse/ADT for the same code line?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, warnings, lint

I'm surprised to see duplicate "Android Lint Warnings" for the following code fragment:

```
122 String contactName = contact.getName();
123 name += contactName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

-> Implicitly using the default local is common source of bugs: Use toUpperCase(Locale) instead; Contact.java; line 123
-> Implicitly using the default local is common source of bugs: Use toUpperCase(Locale) instead; Contact.java; line 123
```

I know how to fix this, but I'm still surprised to see the same warning twice.
Anybody ideas/suggestions, or is this an Android_Lint_Warning-issue?
My development setup: iMac, ADT/Eclipse Build: v22.2.1-833290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, i.e. if you use the following code snippet you only get one warning:

```
122 String contactName = contact.getName();
123 name = name + contactName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

-> Implicitly using the default local is common source of bugs: Use toUpperCase(Locale) instead; Contact.java; line 123
```

Also if you're using something like:

```
123 name = contactName.isEmpty() ? "-" : contactName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
```

you'll get the same two warnings as mentioned before !?!

Probably has to do with building/parsing the expression tree IMHO.